# apache redirect 301 to .php file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess

for our client project we need to redirect all url calls to the matching .php file extension. this is done for SEO (google) ranking. avoiding indexing both url (with *.php and without)

we try to do this using the .htaccess file (shared host) but it seemed to only work for redirects that have a different url and not to the one that just adding the ".php" extension.

different url works

```
abc -> abc2.php
```

same url doesnt work

```
abc -> abc.php
```

here is our code sample:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.abc\.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abc.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L] 

# this doesn't work
Redirect 301 /test http://www.abc.co.uk/test.php

# this redirect works as the url is different
Redirect 301 /test-abc http://www.abc.co.uk/abc.php
```

we host with 1&1 shared host server.
php version is 5.5

I also tried this code that redirects but the page not loading now:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.*)$ http://abc.co.uk/$1.php [R,NC]
```

also noticed url without file extension (.*|html) will not redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .htaccess in `DocumentRoot`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.abc\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abc.co.uk/$1 [R=302,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L,R=302]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it with 302 and 301 and it doesn't work.

Comment: no error, it is not redirecting. try with abc.co.uk/abc  should redirect to abc.co.uk/abc.php

Comment: we really need the .php to work. all the rest is working fine. this line works but page is not loading (url is) RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.*)$ http://www.abc.co.uk/$1.php [R,NC]

Comment: answering directly :) we don't want the 302 we need the 301 redirect. the htaccess is called and processed but in an unusual way (1&1). on other servers our script working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72815/discussion-between-anubhava-and-gadi).

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks 
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L,R=302]

Comment: thanks for your time @anubhava. the last code seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a 302 re-direct, which is not SEO freindly. I tested the above and it doesnt work, also, if it did I wonder what would happen to url's that did not require the .php extension on the URL.

Basically we're trying to get a 301 re-direct working, but it seems to be conflicting with the rules set up that contain the same url. (IE abc > abc.php)

I wonder if there could be some kind of Apache setting or even and unlikely a PHP setting? the 301's work on any other linux server that I try.

Comment: This works perfect:

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L,R=301]

THANK YOU :)